# How to append a variable to an html element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just simply trying to append a variable to an html element using jquery. Where am I going wrong?

```js
var simple = $('<p> hello </p>');
$('.easy').append(simple);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="easy"> </div>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet and it appears to work fine. If your code isn't working you need to ensure you've added a reference to jquery.js in the page and also that you're running your code in a document.ready event handler (which the snippet is adding automatically)

Comment: Yup, it was the document.ready I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your var simple should be a string, without the $.

```
var simple = "<p>hello</p>";
$(".easy").append(simple);
```

Comment: This may be better code, but it's not an issue that would stop the OPs code working - as you can see from the snippet in the question

Comment: append works with both html strings and jQuery elements. I see no benefit to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var simple = '<p> hello </p>';
$('.easy').append(simple);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="easy"> </div>
```

If you want to create HTML template, you can also use `backticks`.

Comment: You don't need backticks for this, do you?

Comment: It is better way to create HTML in JavaScript. Why not?

Comment: The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/#entry-examples) seems to promote quotes for this. I just don't see the benefit of using backticks unless you're using template literals.

Comment: Thank you for the point out. Answer is edited.